# Simple demo of "InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor ..."

Tags: tensorflow, keras

So, I'm experiencing the infamous error (Using Keras with Tensorflow as backend):

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv_in' with dtype float and shape [?,4,4,1]
         [[Node: conv_in = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,4,4,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
         [[Node: conv2d_1/BiasAdd/_47 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_19_conv2d_1/BiasAdd", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

I'm attempting to use a Keras backend (tensorflow) call to access the activations of an intermediate layer of a shared model (a layer/sub-model that's used twice), but can't find a solution to get it to work from the numerous related experiences people have had with the error.

- Background (and ultimate goal):
  The actual project feeds two images into a net, sharing a convolutional subnet, and relating their dense encoding outputs.  My goal was to examine and visualize the convolutional filter activations to see how each image was being processed and improve the model (not the minimal example below, of course).  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to feed in two input images to my main model, and access the activations for one particular instance of the submodel's intermediate layers. Ie. The submodel's conv2d layers have only one output, so how do you access the intermediate activations of the submodel based on its 1st or 2nd use in the main net?

In any case, I can't seem to access the activations at all, due to the error, so that the first problem to resolve...

Here's a complete minimal script demonstrating the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Reshape, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, \
                         Input, Activation, Dropout, AveragePooling2D
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
import keras
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
import ipdb as pdb

def mod_pairs(indim=(None,None), channels=None, lrate=0.01):
    x1 = inp1 = Input(shape=(indim[0], indim[1], channels), name='in1')
    x2 = inp2 = Input(shape=(indim[0], indim[1], channels), name='in2')
    feat = mod_conv(indim=(indim[0], indim[1]), channels=channels)
    x1 = feat(x1)
    x2 = feat(x2)
    x = concatenate([x1,x2], axis=1, name='paired')
    x = Dense(128, name='d_postjoin_1')(x)
    y1 = Dense(1, name='densey1')(x)
    y2 = Dense(1, name='densey2')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2], outputs=[y1, y2])
    adam=Adam(lr=lrate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=adam)
    # print(model.summary())
    return model

def mod_conv(indim=(None,None), channels=None):
    x=inputs=Input(shape=(indim[0], indim[1], channels), name="conv_in")
    x = Conv2D(1, (2,2))(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(5)(x)
    feats = x
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[feats])
    # print("Sub-Model: ConvNet")
    # print(model.summary())
    return model

def main():
    dim=4; ch=1
    mod = mod_pairs(indim=(dim,dim), channels=ch)
    inx1 = np.random.rand(1, dim, dim, ch)
    inx2 = np.random.rand(1, dim, dim, ch)
    y = mod.predict([inx1, inx2])
    print(y)
    cnn = mod.layers[2] # [2] is the mod_conv Model layer
    # print(cnn)  # <keras.engine.training.Model object ...>
    out = mod.layers[2].layers[1]
    # print(out)  # <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object ...>

    # mod.layers[2].layers[1].get_output_at(1)
    # The above results in:
    #  *** ValueError: Asked to get output at node 1, but the layer has only 1 inbound nodes.

    fun = K.function(
        [mod.input[0], mod.input[1], K.learning_phase()],
        [mod.layers[2].layers[1].output])
    #pdb.set_trace()
    # It's about to fail...
    print(fun([inx1, inx2, 0.0]))
    # Errors here ^^^
    # Attempt assuming graph prunes itself without all outputs
    # fails with same error:
    # fun = K.function(
    #   [mod.inputs[0], mod.inputs[1], K.learning_phase()],
    #   [mod.layers[2].layers[1].output] + mod.output)
    # print(fun([inx1, inx2, 0.0]))

main()

# Error output:
#
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "./sharedsubnet.py", line 68, in <module>
#     main()
#   File "./sharedsubnet.py", line 55, in main
#     print(fun([inx1, inx2, 0.0]))
#   File "path.../keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2666, in __call__
#     return self._call(inputs)
#   File "path.../keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2636, in _call
#     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
#   File "path.../tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1382, in __call__
#     run_metadata_ptr)
#   File "path.../tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
#     c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv_in' with dtype float and shape [?,4,4,1]
#          [[Node: conv_in = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,4,4,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add an extra output to your mod_conv() model, then you'll have an easier acces to your particular activation.

```
def mod_conv(indim=(None,None), channels=None):
    x=inputs=Input(shape=(indim[0], indim[1], channels), name="conv_in")
    xconv = Conv2D(1, (2,2))(x)
    x = Flatten()(xconv)
    x = Dense(5)(x)
    feats = x
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[feats,xconv])
    # print("Sub-Model: ConvNet")
    # print(model.summary())
    return model
```

Now your cnn model hast two outputs that hopefully you can use in your K.function() (sorry I didn't understand that part)

```
cnn.get_output_at(0)
cnn.get_output_at(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. This was an approach I do use for multiple outputs, and did try to use in the past for examining activations; however, when evaluating the many various activations of multiple layers of convolutional filters, it becomes quite a mess. :)